# Add color to legend

Tags: r

I have created the following `barplot`, but the problem is that the legends doesn't have the right color, and the grids are in front of the bars. I would like to put the right columns in the boxes at the legend, and put the grid behind the bars.

I also would like to put a tick in the bottom of each bar just to identify them

How can I do these features in R?

[image: barkplot]

The r script that I use:

```
autos_data <- read.table("data.dat", header=T, sep="\t") 

barplot(rep(NA,length(autos_data)),ylim=c(0,max(autos_data)),axes=FALSE)
barplot(t(as.matrix(autos_data)), main=NULL, ylab= "% of Cloud usage", xlab="Input data size (MB)", ylim=c(0,50), beside=TRUE, lwd=1:2, angle=c(45,135), density=seq(5,40,10), col=c("blue","red","black","darkgreen"))
grid(NA, 5, lwd=1,lty=5, col="gray") # grid only in y-direction  

# Place the legend at the top-left corner with no frame
coords="top"
legend(coords, c("WestVirginia","Chicago I","Chicago II","California"), text.col=par("col"), cex=1.2, bty="n", xpd=TRUE, horiz=TRUE, inset=c(0,-.22), angle=c(35,135,45,135), density=seq(5,40,10),col=c("blue","red","black","darkgreen"))
```

Edit:

```
dput(autos_data)
structure(list(WestVirginia = c(29L, 29L, 23L, 23L), ChicagoI = c(30L, 
21L, 36L, 26L), ChicagoII = c(39L, 42L, 35L, 46L), California = c(2L, 
8L, 6L, 5L)), .Names = c("WestVirginia", "ChicagoI", "ChicagoII", 
"California"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1500", "3000", 
"4500", "6000"))
```

The data:

```
West-Virginia   ChicagoI    ChicagoII   California
1500    29  30  39  2
3000    29  21  42  8
4500    23  36  35  6
6000    23  26  46  5
```

Comment: can you `dput(autos_data)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute the legend directly in the `barplot` call, specifying the arguments via `args.legend` parameter and the text via `legend.text`. For the grid, you need to replot the `barplot` after setting the grid, with white and then the lines so the grid doesn't appear anymore in the lines:

It needs 3 calls of the same `barplot` but I think it gives you what you want:

```
# first plot
barplot(t(as.matrix(autos_data)), main=NULL, axes=FALSE, beside=TRUE, col="white", ylab= "% of Cloud usage", xlab="Input data size (MB)", ylim=c(0,50))
# add the grid
grid(NA, 5, lwd=1,lty=5, col="gray") # grid only in y-direction  
# hide the grid with white bars
barplot(t(as.matrix(autos_data)), main=NULL, beside=TRUE, col="white", ylab= "% of Cloud usage", xlab="Input data size (MB)", ylim=c(0,50), add=TRUE)
# plot the density lines, the legend, etc.
barplot(t(as.matrix(autos_data)), main=NULL, axes=FALSE, beside=TRUE, 
        lwd=1:2, angle=c(45,135), density=seq(5,40,10), col=c("blue","red","black","darkgreen"), 
        legend.text=c("WestVirginia","Chicago I","Chicago II","California"), 
        args.legend=list(x="top", y=NULL, bty="n", ncol=4), add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is an inconsistency of parameter names.

You need to set `fill`:

```
legend(coords, c("WestVirginia","Chicago I","Chicago II","California"), text.col=par("col"), 
       cex=1.2, bty="n", xpd=TRUE, horiz=TRUE, inset=c(0,-.22), angle=c(35,135,45,135), 
       density=seq(5,40,10), fill=c("blue","red","black","darkgreen"))
```

[image]

Comment: Cleaner than my answer (now deleted)

Answer (score 0):

In your `legend` set `fill` rather than `col`

```
legend(
  coords, 
  legend = c("WestVirginia","Chicago I","Chicago II","California"), 
  text.col=par("col"), 
  cex=1.2, 
  bty="n", 
  xpd=TRUE,
  horiz=TRUE, 
  inset=c(0,-.22), 
  angle=c(35,135,45,135), 
  density=seq(5,40,10),
  fill=c("blue","red","black","darkgreen")
)
```